# C++ - How do i put a whole char-array in a pointer?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters, c-strings

I´m a beginner (and didn´t find an answer on the internet). I got a pointer and a char array and want to save the entire Array, not only the first element, in a pointer to give it to a function (also, im not allowed to change the function parameters).

```
char Feld[ ] = {1,2,3}          
char *pointer = NULL;
pointer = ???
```

function:

```
void strncat(char *s)
{...}
```

Call function:

```
strncat(???)
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: A pointer can only point at one address in memory. But you can access the whole string from this one pointer as all other characters are right after the first.

Comment: If you are learning C++ (rather than C) you should not start by using `char*` for strings, but `std::string` instead. Pointers should not be taught at the beginning. Of course it may be that you cannot change anything about this situation, but I just want to let you know.

Comment: Please explain in more detail what you expect to happen, preferably with a [repro]. It is really not clear to me what you want to do. Are the numbers `1`, `2`, `3` supposed to represent the corresponding characters by ASCII codes or do you want a string that contains theses digit characters?

Answer (score 2):

If the function is declared the following way

```
void strncat(char *s);
```

then it means that the function does no know the size of the array pointed to by the pointer `s`. So it seems the function deals with a string: a sequence of characters terminated by a zero character.

On the other hand, using the letter `'n'` in the function name `strncat`  means that the function should have one more parameter that specifies the length of the used character array.

So either the function is declaraed incorrectly or it should be renamed as for example

```
void strcat(char *s);
```

Or it is better to declare it like

```
char * strcat(char *s);
```

Hence this declaration of a character array

```
char Feld[ ] = {1,2,3};
```

can not be used in the function because the array does not contain a string and its length is not passed to the function.

You should declare the array for example like

```
char Feld[ ] = { '1','2','3', '\0' };
```

or like

```
char Feld[ ] = "123"; // or { "123" }
```

Pointers do not keep the information whether they point to a single object or the first element of an array.

So if the function is declared as shown above then you should just write

```
char *p = Feld; 
strcat( p );
```

or without using the intermediate pointer like

```
strcat( Feld );
```

Within the function the length of the string will be determinate by the number of characters before the terminating zero `'\0'`.

Answer (score 0):

`Feld` is a pointer to the first element of the Array. So you can pass `strncat(Feld)`.
If you want you can also do `char* pointer = Feld;` and `strncat(pointer)` but there's really no need for that. You can then access the other elements with `s[0],s[1],s[2]`. As @Vlad pointed out you can't assign integers to a char array rather you need to do `char Feld[ ] = {'1','2','3'}`